# Generating and downloading hundreds of files in Javascript - How to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically generating multiple ~2mb files and downloading them in sequence for an internal application. The code works but when it reaches about 55 images the page stops and gives me a "status breakpoint" error.

I went to the memory tab in the chrome devtools and saw that at every loop the memory footprint increases, so I believe the blobs being generated are not being disposed for some reason.. here's my code:

```
  capturer.save(blob => {
    // const link = document.createElement("a");
    let downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloader.href = downloadURL;
    downloader.download = currentImage + ".gif";
    downloader.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click"));

    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blob);
    // tried these, no effect

    if (startImage< endImage) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.imageExport(++startImage, endImage);
      }, 0);
    }
  });
```

As you can see, I was initially creating elements dynamically but then I commented it out and added a single downloader element to test, didn't work. I believe the blobs are piling up on the memory and I can't find a way to dispose them.

Any ideas? I've been trying to fix this for hours now.

Comment: `URL.revokeObjectUrl(..)`? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL)  I'm not sure if you're supposed to pass `blob` or `downloader.href`.

Comment: Interesting, I tried it yet didn't make any difference, updated the question

Comment: Why don't you just use an Ajax call?

Comment: Images are dynamically generated into a blob. These images are stored in memory.

Comment: I guess it's not a matter of solely calling `URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL)`, that will only remove the URL which points at the blob in memory. You might just have a memory leak in another part of your app. If you can't share all the code, memory tab and some debugging can help,  :)